# Выдает ошибку при создании таблицы

Tags: mysql

```
create table order
    -> (order_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
    -> status varchar(20),
    -> price int,
    -> expected_price int,
    -> date date,
    -> employee_id smallint unsigned not null,
    -> customer_id smallint unsigned not null,
    -> service_id smallint unsigned not null,
    -> constraint pk_order primary key(order_id)
    -> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order
(order_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
status varchar(20),
' at line 1
```

Comment: Так написано что сделать - проверить правильность синтаксиса для соответствующей версии.

Comment: потому что `order` - зарезервированное слово в мускл http://spec-zone.ru/RU/mysql/5.6/language-structure_reserved-words.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137910/how-can-i-make-a-table-in-mysql-called-order